# Query for fetching data from tables

Tags: mysql

I am having following tables

```
subject(id,name,sem,branch) //Detail of subject in sem and branch
teacher(id,name,dept) //detail of teacher
student_teacher_mapping(sid,tid) //primary key of student and teacher
section(id,sec) //detail of sections
subject_section_mapping(sid,secid) //primary key of subject and section
```

I want to fetch subject name and teacher names of branch "COMPUTER SCIENCE" ,sem=3 and section='d'.

Comment: @eggyal branch "COMPUTER SCIENCE" ,sem=3 and section='d'

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @tombom trying to create feedback application

Comment: @Manish tombom is asking WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED?

Comment: Okay, it's not homework. Still this is not a "we do the work for you" site. We help when there are specific problems, preferably in a way with which people learn something. You don't learn anything by copy&pasting. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Manish Who made this database structure anyway?

Comment: @techie_28 I made it, is there any problem

Answer (score 0):

@Manish You see your table SUBJECT is linked to SECTION which will give us a SECTION and that table SECTION is not linked to any other table,So there seems to be a dead end here and the datbase design seems to be wrong.

Comment: SO section and teacher should also map.  I have created teacher,student,section and student table and their 2 mapping table as above. Based on student's Branch, Semester and section i want to fetch Subject and teacher in a jsp page then student will give feedback of teacher. The feedback will store in feedbackval table.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done it without your help :/

I changed in one table
My tables are

```
subject(id,name,sem,branch) //Detail of subject in sem and branch
teacher(id,name,dept) //detail of teacher
section(id,sec) //detail of sections
sub_teacher_sec (subject_id,teacher_id,section_id) //primary key of subject,teacher and section
```

This is my query to fetch subject name, teacher name and section for spacific branch semester and section value

```
select sub.name,t.name,se.sec from subjects as sub
  join
sub_teacher_sec as sts
  on
sts.subject_id=sub.id
 join
teachers as t
  on
sts.teacher_id=t.id
 join
section as se
   on
sts.section_id=se.id
and  sub.semester=3 and sub.branch='CSE';
```

Is there any correction in table or in query please suggest.